# how do I simply run latest examples of project like web ui or widgets

Tags: dart, dart-webui

If something I have specifies web ui in its pubspec it eventually ends up in a place like $HOME/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web_ui-0.4.7+3. I noticed that the todomvc appears in the example folder. I was hoping to just run all the examples, so I loaded the existing folder web_ui-0.4.7+3 into the darteditor. Then tried pub install/update and build. That did not work due to the '+' in the folder name.

So, next I just git cloned the web-ui project and tried to pub update similarly. The issue is "web_ui requires SDK version >=0.5.7+1 but the current SDK is 0.5.5+0.r22416", which I can understand - what is out on github is more bleeding edge. I update whenever the icon on DartEditor indicates it is time to, but here it seems if you get the latest of a package it can depend on a later SDK than you have with the editor. I have had the same issue when I clone a package such as 'widgets'. The author said the issue was going directly to github instead of using pub and that if I used pub it would be OK. I'm not clear on what that means, because to me using pub means I have a project in which I pull in and use a specific library and maybe resources. But to just run the latest of /examples/ in a project like web ui or widgets do I need to create my own project and reference them to run them?

So, first what is going on, in the sense that what develompent process has developers on later versions of SDK. If you just rely on DartEditor to update SDK and only use pubspec - this is probably not an issue. But, is it easy to have two setups, one the latest from perspective of what is released with DartEditor and another with latest SDK and if so how?

I figured out that I could just copy the existing web_ui-0.4.7+3 to /tmp/web_ui then successfully load into dart editor and run, (breakpoints not yet working for me on Mac). But would still like to know how to run on latest and what is most sensible way to just get a package and run it's examples.

Comment: The current version of Dart is 0.5.7.3_r22659 released Tuesday evening. However the required version, 0.5.7.2_r22611 was released monday evening. You can get notices from: announce@dartlang.org mailing list. Update editor by going to "help" and "about dart editor"

Comment: Thanks, but my "help" has no "about dart editor", just search, "key assist" and a few other options. I'm less interested in the specific versions as to what process is used to use the latest SDK, which it seems is being done by developers of libraries like "widgets". Maybe this is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: I provided a full answer on how to run examples. As for running the latest editor and sdk, there are two possible ways. One option is developers wait for the announcement about the latest verion, they update and ensure their code conforms. The other is that they run the bleeding edge version of the editor, downloading it fresh daily from: https://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/ but that's really up to each package maintainer and some will choose different methods for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment on the editor version.

Regarding examples. Currently examples with a package are not easily accessed from the pub cache. I was unable to find a bug specifically on making this available though I believe it was planed. I created a separate [Issue 10668](http://dartbug.com/10668) for this.

In the mean time, one solution is to clone the git-hub repository to get the examples as you mentioned. But as you have also discovered these are usually development versions and can vary or break from the versions you have installed.

Another solution is to locate the package on the [Pub Repository](http://pub.dartlang.org). Such as the [Web_ui package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_ui). On that page, you can click on the 'versions' tab at the top to see a list of all stable versions that have been released.

On this page you can download the entire package, similar to cloning the repository but with the stable version, and extract it to a directory of your choosing. You should then be able to load the full project into your editor. You will need to load the full project into the editor, not just the example directory. Run pub install if it doesn't do so automatically, and then you should be able to run the examples.

Regarding running multiple versions: Some package developers choose to keep two installations of the Dart Editor. One is the stable version released weekly and updated through the editor itself. The other is to use the dart continuous build which is usually updated at least once a day and sometimes more often. In these cases I know of some developers who setup a script to automatically download the latest continuous build each morning and extract it. The [Dart Editor](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/) page provides a link to the latest continuous build just under the links to the stable downloads. The continuous build is bleeding_edge version so may break from time to time.